# User.IsInRole doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, simplemembership, .aspxauth

I have ASP.NET MVC 4 application. I use Simple Membership Provider allowing to tick remember me checkbox under login form. If ticked, persitent cookie .ASPXAUTH is created which expires 100 days from login date. And everything works fine, apart of main menu of the application.

Some parts of the menu are available for admin users only. I use:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Administrator")) { @Html.Partial("_MainMenuPartial") }
```

to lock them from being rendered for regular user. This approach works fine just after logging into the system. When I return after a while and persistent cookie is used to authenticate me, I do get logged in, but

```
@User.IsInRole("Administrator")
```

returns "False" so I can't see admin menu items. At the same time

```
@User.Identity.Name
```

returns proper login name and

```
@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

returns "True", what proves that persistent cookie works fine. Why can't I access user roles even though user is authenticated by the system then?

Comment: How have you actually created roles? When do actually assign roles to users - in your Register ActionResult?

Comment: Yes, this is how I do it in Register action: Roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { model.UserName }, new[] { role }); While role is a string determined earlier.

Comment: A safer way to do it is in your InitialiseSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs class: just under `Websecurity.InitialiseDatabaseConnection` use `if (!Roles.RoleExists("Admin")) Roles.CreateRole("Admin");`. Did you try and use the overloaded method I described in my answer.

Comment: The solution I found to this problem was adding a filter in the RegisterGlobalFilters method of the FilterConfig class in the App_Start folder. See this for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215316/simplemembershipprovider-roles-not-accessible/16219020#16219020

Answer (score 32):

I had a smilar issue. In my case the problem solved when i log off and log in again.

Comment: The reason this works: https://forums.asp.net/post/5569366.aspx

Answer (score 21):

Problem using roles with MVC5

I found a solution.  In my web.config:

```
<modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    <remove name="RoleManager" />
</modules>
```

I added remove name="RoleManager" line, and the new AspNet.Identity code took over allowing me to use User.IsInRole(..)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1952572.aspx?Problem+using+roles+with+MVC5

Comment: Yes worked in VS2015 on Win10 (when it hadn't been a problem on a different machine.  Thank you!

Comment: It worked for me too, but im concerned as to what are the consequences of removing the RoleManager. At first my site seems to look ok but I don't know when I should be concerned (what other features I have just removed). Anyone?

Comment: I tried lot of other ways. But finally this worked for me

Answer (score 8):

Old question, but there's some missing information here. I ran into the same issue, and there's one thing to keep in mind. If you test the user identity (*like User.IsInRole("admin")*) just after authenticate (**without send the response to client**), Identity framework **has not populated this session info yet** (or at least, I could not found the way to do that). This info you're requesting for, is populated at some point after your controller return. If you want (I.E.) to redirect to different views after login, depending on the user role, you'll have to use a custom authorization filter.

Comment: Yeah what I do is redirect to another page after login. Then I can get roles of the user on that page.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried adding

```
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
```

in the controller where you're doing the check?

Comment: I had the same issue and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using latest Identity framework please see if you are using following

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<WebUserContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

If you are using AddDefaultIdentity Roles don't get populated.

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<WebUserContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the most up-to-date answer.

Comment: Also for links to work out of the box you need to include `.AddDefaultUI()`

Comment: This fixed me, I have an asp.net app with db for indenty and I am building one in net core to upgrade to but dont want all the users to have to have two sets of credentials and roles. I modified program.cs with this builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultUI(); thanks @kyle Barnes for the added info too

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with `IsUserInRole` returning false. By placing a watch on it, I was able to overcome the problem by using the overload described below. Try it, put a break point where you're getting false, and see what happens.

```
@if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Model.UserName, "Administrator"))
```

I'm pretty sure you could also use `User.Identity.Name` as the first parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, seems like authentication module is not wired up completely with the SimpleMembershipProvider. To get around that problem, you can use a Role class to access needed information. For example to check if the use in role you can use the following:

```
Roles.GetRolesForUser("sergey").Contains("Developer")
```

And so other useful methods when working wit SimpleMembershipProvider roles:

```
   Roles.RoleExists("Developer")
   Roles.CreateRole("Developer");
   Roles.AddUserToRole("sergey", "Developer");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution doesn't work for me: alert("@User.IsInRole("Administrator")");         alert("@Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name).Contains("Administrator")"); both return False

Comment: Can you try to see if there are any roles at all on that user?
string.Join(",", Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name))

Comment: alert("@string.Join(",", Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name))"); returns empty string

Comment: Do you know for fact that your user has roles? Try to assign roles first with Roles.CreateRole("Developer"); Roles.AddUserToRole("sergey", "Developer"); And then check if roles exist. Good luck.

Comment: As I've mentioned before, roles exist. If I'll log out and log in back again I'll be recognized as an "Administrator". It's just when I return to the application after a while and am authenticated by the cookie roles magically disappear.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using IdentityManager by Brock Allen to create roles and assign them to users then you should read this article: https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager.AspNetIdentity/issues/3

You'll need to uncomment the following line:

```
this.RoleClaimType = System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role;
```

Now you'll realize that your user that used to be in roles is no longer in them, and you'll have to re add them. If you take a look at the AspNetUserClaims table, you'll see claimType of Role and 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role' you want the later.

Once you do this, `User.IsInRole("rolename")` behaves as expected.

I hope this helps someone, took me a while to figure this out.

Comment: This occurs because by default `IdentityManager.Configuration.SecurityConfiguration.RoleClaimType` is set to `Constants.ClaimTypes.Role`, i.e. to "role", yet `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole(string role)` does `HasClaim(m_identities[i].RoleClaimType, role)`, where `RoleClaimType` is "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role". Problem with your fix, which works, is that one won't be able to use claim "role" in UI anymore and would have to go with that long string.

Answer (score 2):

The "EmailConfirmed" of this account probably still false, try to change it to true

[image: Database Screenshot]

Comment: This is what worked for me

Answer (score 2):

None of these answers worked for me, but I did find the answer here: https://thinkthencode.wordpress.com/2016/04/24/azure-ad-using-app-roles-for-authorization/

The key was adding the following to `Startup.Auth.cs`:

```
TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    RoleClaimType = "roles"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but in my case the problem was that the Session timeout was not synced with the authentication timeout, so I was not kicked out automatically but my session was being expired and, since my allowed operations were stored in a Session Variable, I was not able to retrieve the correct options for the current user.

Try checking if your session is not expired even if you're still logged in

Comment: I don't really use session variable anywhere within the application.

Answer (score 1):

Quite old topic but can confirm in vs 2015 Web forms application works solution:

```
<modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    <remove name="RoleManager" /> <!--add this to web config-->
</modules>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with the MVC5 role manager for some time now. I've verified that `User.IsInRole` can return different results at the same time, and apparently this is because the `User` object is cached and needs to be invalidated. One way to do this is to log out and log back in again as one of the answers here specified. Just throw this in the controller that adds the new role:

```
        UserManager.AddToRole(User.Identity.GetUserId(), "Administrator");

        var updatedUser = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
        var newIdentity = await updatedUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager);
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(newIdentity);
```

However, if the user has your application open in other windows this won't update all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Clear all cookies and try to login again. If we changed our roles, the cookie might not be aware of it. Reset the Cookies and create a cookie with your new roles and try again.

Answer (score 0):

> Paste this code in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpCookie authCookie =
                Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
            if (authCookie != null)
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket =
                    FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
                string[] roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
                GenericPrincipal userPrincipal =
                    new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name), roles);
                Context.User = userPrincipal;
            }
        }

        protected class RolesAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
        {
            public RolesAttribute(params string[] roles)
            {
                Roles = String.Join(",", roles);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things could be going on and here are few general things to try:

1. Try to run in debug mode and make sure that the line of code gets executed - silly but might happen
2. As stated in other answers, try to log off and log back in
3. Make sure the role is spelled out correctly
4. Make sure that the proper user is assigned to the proper role id
5. Try to republish the entire solution to the server - in my case, everything worked fine locally but not on the server until full delete all and republish
6. If all fails, try to run out of a box project and test it before adding complexity

Answer (score 0):

```
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager

...

await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User),"admin")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

Add Page in front of User. This works:  `Page.User.IsInRole("Administrator")`

Answer (score -6):

For my code it had to be plural, not singular:

```
User.IsInRole("Administrators")
```

Comment: This answer isn't really relevant - just because the string value is different doesn't justify another answer

Comment: It might help you to understand that the Role string that matches here needs to the entry done in the default `AspNetRoles` table setup in your DB in the `Name` column