# Why does @User.IsInRole always return false in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I am using Razor-Pages to develop a web app. In my _Layout.cshtml file, I want to change the menu according to the role of the current user.
I, therefore, use `User.IsInRole(string role)` but it always returns false.

In a similar question, I read that it's somehow not possible to retrieve the user-role right after login. However, I don't understand why that would be the case.

My code:

```
@if (User.IsInRole(Roles.Admin.ToString())) {
  <li><a asp-page="/AdminMenuPoint">Admin Menu</a>a/li>
}
```

My roles enum:

```
public enum Roles {
  Supervisor, Admin
};
```

To summarize: Why doesn't `User.IsInRole()` work for my hompage (after login)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you got `enabled="true"` for `roleManager` in the web.config?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567338/user-isinrole-doesnt-work

Comment: Have you wired up ASP Identity to use your `Roles` enum? There should be something like `services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()` in the `ConfigureServices` method of your Startup file.

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia I just did. It still doesn't work tho.

Comment: as in comment by @st_stefanov try: `<modules>
<remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
<remove name="RoleManager" />
</modules>`

Comment: @PatrickStephansen In `ConfigureServices` I have both `services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()` and `services.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()`. For testing purposes, I seed users with roles as follows: `roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Roles.Admin.ToString()))`

Comment: outside `<system.web>` inside `<system.webServer>` - I have added it as an answer as it is too difficult to show you in a comment... if it does not work i will delete it.

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia It still doesn't work :(

Comment: have you try to add the user to a role, like calling `await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(User, Roles.Admin.ToString())` and check the database to ensure that the setting persisted?

Comment: @riza Yes, that's exactly what I did. I've also checked the database and both the roles and the connection between role and user is as I expected...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use .Net Core you need to setup:

1. Add Identity Service in Startup.cs

**Edited**

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
   .AddRoles<IdentityRole>() // <-- Add this line
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

According to [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1813#issuecomment-420066501), getting the roles and claims to show up in the cookie involves *either* reverting to the `service.AddIdentity` initialization code, or sticking with `service.AddDefaultIdentity` and adding this line of code to `ConfigureServices`:

```
// Add Role claims to the User object
// See: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1813#issuecomment-420066501
services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>>();
```

2. Create Role and Assign User for Role

```
private async Task CreateUserRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
 var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
 var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();

 IdentityResult roleResult;
 //Adding Admin Role
 var roleCheck = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin");
 if (!roleCheck)
 {
 //create the roles and seed them to the database
 roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
 }
 //Assign Admin role to the main User here we have given our newly registered 
 //login id for Admin management
 ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync("syedshanumcain@gmail.com");
 var User = new ApplicationUser();
 await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that's not my problem. The seeding of users and their roles seems not to be the problem

Comment: @Jimmy are the user assigned to roles on table ASPNetUserRoles?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just checked `AspNetUserRoles` in my database and the data seeding worked fine. So yeah, the users are correctly assigned to their respective roles...

Comment: Hi @Jimmy have you try add this to services?`services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>>();`

Comment: Thank you so much man! I didn't see you'd edited your solution. I just added `services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>>();` and it works like a charm. Thanks man:)