# Authorize using Windows Computer Management Local Users and Groups

Tags: c#, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API that I only want users of a certain group be able to access. I don't have Active Directory, instead I want to use Windows' Computer Management Local Users and Groups to grant permissions. I have tried a few ways to make this happen such as:

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("RequireWindowsGroupMembership", policy =>
                {
                    policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    policy.RequireRole("ADMIN_PORTAL_ACCESS");
                    });
                });
            });
```

and

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("RequireWindowsGroupMembership", policy =>
                {
                    policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                    {
                        return context.User.IsInRole("ADMIN_PORTAL_ACCESS"); // also tried "MYDOMAIN\\ADMIN_PORTAL_ACCESS"
                    });
                });
            });
```

And I'm adding `[Authorize(Policy = "RequireWindowsGroupMembership")]` to each of my controllers. I am getting a http 403 error on each request.

I also tried using just `[Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN_PORTAL_ACCESS")]`.

Authentication seems to be working fine because my endpoint

```
[HttpGet]
public string Get()
{
    IPrincipal p = HttpContext.User;
    return p.Identity.Name;
}
```

This will return whatever Windows user is logged in as (even will prompt a login window if accessing from outside the server that I am hosting this on). It seems like the authorization on the group is the issue.

Any ideas on how to get this working? I am also not completely tied to using Local Users and Groups, just as long as I can assign roles

Answer (score 1):

After my test according to the official document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-8.0 , your **role-based** authorization cannot work with the **[Authorize(Policy)]** , and **policy-based** authorization should not contain the **role requirement**. My username is Administrator and my role is Administrator too.

[image]

Meanwhile, you need to start the windows authentication on **IIS Express** or **Http.sys** in your local environment https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio . It may be the cause why your application failed.

**Controller**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace CookieAuthSampleAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpGet("admin")]
        public IActionResult GetAdminData()
        {
            // Your code here. This will be accessible only to users in the specified Windows group.
            return Ok("This is secure data available to users with the 'Administrator' role.");
        }

        [HttpGet("get")]
        public string Get()
        {
            IPrincipal p = HttpContext.User;
            return p.Identity.Name;
        }

    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using LocalManually.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlConnection")));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole",
         policy => {
             policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
             policy.RequireRole("Administrator");
         });
});

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**Setting in launchSettings.json**

```
"$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
"iisSettings": {
  "windowsAuthentication": true,
  "anonymousAuthentication": false,
  "iisExpress": {
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51110",
    "sslPort": 44329
  }
},
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. While testing this approach I found - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26655162/5594068 which just says to log in and out which ended up working.